# breakpoint on all files from a certain directory

Tags: python, terminal, pdb

I like to use `ipdb` to debug my code. I know we could stop the code on a file on a specific line with `b(reak) file:lineno`. That command will set a breakpoint in `file` at line 'no'.

Actually, I have inserted `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` on a specific file. Each time I use the command `s(tep)`, it executes and step into functions. My problem is it is too slow before seeing what I want to see. The stacktrace showed me lines I do not necessarily want to see. Then I was thinking to put a breakpoint on all files from a certain directory, i.e., `b mydirectory/**`. Therefore, eachtime I will execute `c`, it will show me all lines I want to see. However, I can't execute such command (i.e., `b mydirectory/**`). Could anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

**P.S.** The following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiuaG.png) show ton of those irrelevant files I don't want to see. In fact, it is normal to see those files, because I am working on a django project.

Please tell me if the question is unclear

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but I would strongly suggest getting a proper IDE that allows runtime debug. I personally like pycharm a lot, but I haven't used it with django. Understand that the time you take to setup the project in the IDE is usually recovered pretty quickly in overall development speed

Comment: @Eric I have already used pycharm and clearly it is a limited IDE. I don't want to use that. I am currently using vim, and it is great for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pdb; pdb.Pdb(skip=['mydirectory.*']).set_trace()
```

mydirectory have to be a python module, here is more info from the documentaion

> The skip argument, if given, must be an iterable of glob-style module
>   name patterns. The debugger will not step into frames that originate
>   in a module that matches one of these patterns. [1]

source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#pdb.Pdb